# Updating a database from data grid view after displaying and editing results from a query

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I am new to using C# as a front end to view and edit a database. I can bring up a database query and display the results using a data grid view using the code bellow.

```
     private void btnconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Accode", "Accode");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("CaseNO", "Case NO");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Doccumentname", "Document Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("CreatedDate", "Created Date");


        string strFile = txtFileName.Text;
        string strPass = "********";
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strFile + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + strPass + ";";
        connect.Open();

    if (txtCaseNo.Text != "" && txtAccode.Text != "")
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT CorrespondenceHistory.Accode, CorrespondenceHistory.CaseNo,CorrespondenceHistory.DocumentName, CorrespondenceHistory.CreatedDate FROM CorrespondenceHistory WHERE (((CorrespondenceHistory.CaseNo)=" + txtCaseNo.Text + "),((CorrespondenceHistory.Accode)=" + txtAccode.Text + "))";

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Accode"].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["CaseNO"].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Doccumentname"].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["CreatedDate"].Value = reader[3].ToString();

            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a search criteria", "Enter a search criteria");

        connect.Close();
       }
```

But I am unsure of how to get it to update the database table to any changes made in the data grid view. As the program is going to be used on multiple computer (all with the same database and password) the location of the database changes, hence it taking from a text box when making the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want a desktop or web-based application.  If you opt for a web-based application, then you can specify InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, SelectCommand, etc., to perform operations.  For details please see http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1.

Comment: It is just a desktop application, that can be opened that one query altered and updated, as that is a large database and a lot of the people using needing to edit that one part, don't have the password for it, and can't be given it. So with this front end it will enable them to edit it with out us having to give out access to anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with the standard Windows Forms data grid view; however, I know that if you use Infragistics UI controls you can edit in a grid: http://blogs.infragistics.com/winforms/codesamples/archives/79097.aspx